# If an ACK packet is lost will a SYN packet be resent with the same sequence number?

Tags: tcp

Supposed an ACK packet is lost in transmission, and after that timeout, the original packet is resent. Will this duplicate packet contain the same sequence number?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this will have same sequence number for the retransmission.

Answer (score 0):

I think the resent `SYN` should have different `ISN` (`Initial Sequence Number`). The following words are from 
**13.2.3 Initial Sequence Number (ISN)**, [TCP/IP Illustrated, Volume 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321336313):

> Before each end sends its SYN to establish the connection, it chooses an ISN for that connection. The ISN should change over time, so that each connection has a different one. [RFC0793] specifies that the ISN should be viewed as a 32-bit counter that increments by 1 every 4μs. The purpose of doing this is to arrange for the sequence numbers for segments on one connection to not overlap with sequence numbers on a another (new) identical connection. In particular, new sequence numbers must not be allowed to overlap between different instantiations (or incarnations) of the same connection.